# Форматирование строк. Избавиться от кавычек в SQL-запросе

Tags: python, sql, строки, postgresql, psycopg2

Следующая команда дает ошибку при запуске:

```
dbname = "test"
cursor.execute(cursor.mogrify("DROP DATABASE %s;"), (dbname,))
```

Подобное ей также возвращает ошибку:

```
cursor.execute("DROP DATABASE %s;", (dbname,))
```

Ошибка:

```
Error syntax error at or near "'test'"
LINE 1: DROP DATABASE 'test';
```

Причина - одинарные кавычки. Как от них избавиться?

Comment: Скорее всего схемы test нет в базе. Кавычки тут не при чём. И точку с запятой после команды не забыли?

Comment: @Smithson В случае отсутствия базы ошибка была бы другой, типа - Error FATAL:  database "test" does not exist. Точка с запятой есть

Comment: execute не приспособлен для подстановки параметров в операторы DDL (в т.ч. drop table). формируйте команду сами, дедовским способом, просто подставляя саму переменную в текст (не забыв пофиксить в ней недопустимые символы для защиты от sql-инъекций)

Comment: @Mike как понимаю, отдельно от команды сформировать строку дропа таблицы и уже ее в execute? приведите, пожалуйста, пример команды и недопустимых символов, а лучше толковый мануал на эту тему. пишите в ответах, я оценю. ваш комментарий полезный

Comment: @Mike то, что execute не приспособлен для операторов DDL это намеренное ограничение для безопасности?

Comment: Я питона не знаю :) как у вас строки объединяются, плюсом или точкой или еще чем. ну тупо execute('drop table '+dbname+';'). просто так библиотеки работы с БД устроены во всех языках. в вашем случае думаю достаточно не допустить в dbname точек с запятой, что бы после нее вторую команду не написали

Comment: А по поводу ограничений ... ну так сделано, думаю потому, что бибилотеки расчитаны на передачу параметров определенных типов данных. А такого типа данных как "имя объекта БД" не предусмотрено в самих БД

Comment: Даже на уровне синтаксиса самого sql, из хранимых процедур, переменные как параметры в запросы подставлять можно, а когда сталкивашся с DDL все равно пишешь вызов динамического sql собирая строку руками ...

Comment: @Mike спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Собирите DDL предварительно в переменной и передайте её в execute.

Или что-то такое поробуйте, если действительно нужно:

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
...
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE %(table)s", {"table": AsIs("my_table")})
```

Для DML тоже может пригодиться, например:

```
'select * from t order by %s', (AsIs('col1, col2 desc'),)
```

Comment: Спасибо, по поводу предварительной сборки уже посказали, за второй способ - спасибо